# Is there a way to make a graphicimage in Primefaces execute the "value" method only on demand?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, graphicimage

I want to show a custom gallery with several thumbnails. When clicking on one of these, an overlaypanel is shown, containing a graphicimage with the image in higher quality. Since the high quality images are aroung 5MB each, I just want to load them on demand.

I already tried using the "rendered" attribute, but that did not seem to do the trick either. I also tried the "onclick" with a javascript function, but that also did not yield the expected result.

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{dataHolderBean.imageHolderBean.loadFullSizeImage()}"
class="centeredImageOverlay" cache="false">
<f:param name="currentImageId" value="#{images.imageId}" />
</p:graphicImage>
```

I would like to just call value="#{dataHolderBean.imageHolderBean.loadFullSizeImage()}" this method, when clicking on another image.

Comment: Why not look for a solution that loads the **content of the overlay panel** lazy? Sounds like a much more generic solution and a higher chance of something already being implemented

Comment: @Kukeltje That is a great idea! Still can't find a working solution for that though :/

Comment: **always, always, always** try to see a more generic question/problem behind a specific one. Much more chance on finding a solution then. And the PF showcase has a working solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you not look for a solution that loads the content of the overlay panel lazy? That to me sounds like a much more generic solution (anything inside it would be loaded lazy then) you stand and a higher chance of something already being implemented.

From the PrimeFaces showcase of the `p:overlayPanel`(emphasis mine)

> **Overlay Panel**
>
> OverlayPanel is a generic container component that can overlay other
>   components on page. Notable features are custom positioning,
>   configurable events and effects. **Lazy content loading to reduce page
>   load time is also supported via dynamic option, when enabled
>   overlayPanel will load the contents just before being shown.**

From the PrimeFaces documentation

> **Dynamic Mode**
>
> Dynamic mode enables lazy loading of the content, in this
>   mode content of the panel is not rendered on page load and loaded just
>   before panel is shown. Also content is cached so consecutive displays
>   do not load the content again. This feature is useful to reduce the
>   page size and reduce page load time.

So the lazy loading is done via the `dynamic` attribute which has an example even in the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/overlayPanel.xhtml)

```
<p:commandButton id="movieBtn" value="Dynamic" type="button" />
<p:overlayPanel id="moviePanel" for="movieBtn" hideEffect="fade" dynamic="true" style="width:600px" modal="true">
    ...
</p:overlayPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me here. I will also try to find more generic solutions from now on. I have been working on this for a coupld of days now, not really getting anywhere :/
Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in LazyDefaultStreamedContent in your bean, to lazy initialize the stream:

```
streamedContent = new LazyDefaultStreamedContent("application/vnd.ms-excel", "myExcel") {
    @Override
    protected InputStream initStream()
    {
          return new FileInputStream(...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this work for images too? And when is it loaded then? I sort of fail to see (and that is very likely to be related to my limited view/knowledge) where this would fix something in the question above. If you can add some explanation, that would be great (and worth an upvote)

Comment: Well, this would not solve my problem, but it helped me by replacing my "DefaultStreamedContent". Thank you!